# With the clear session flag set to FALSE, I am missing the published values

Tags: android, mqtt, messagebroker, paho

Is anyone has a logical explanation why despite I have the `clear session flage = false` I do not receive the updated published message I am subscribed to while i am not connected to the broker?

With the aorementioned flag set to false I ran my App, And i kept publishing to a topic some values (from the PC to the broker not from the Android device to the broker). And then I unpluged the usb of the Android Device frm the pc, and kept publishing some values again. When I plugged the usb to the pc again, i expected to see the values I recently published to that topic, but I did not receive any.

The topic I am publishing to is exactly the topic i am subscribed to, with `QoS = 1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for messages to be queued for a client that is no longer connected to a broker, these things must be true:

- Client must have originally connected with `clean session` set to false
- Client must have subscribed with QoS>0
- Messages to that topic must have been published with QoS>0
- When the client reconnects it must have the same `client id` as when it disconnected
- When the client reconnects it must have `clean session` set to false

My bet is that you are failing on either of the latter two points.

Comment: so clear, i reconnect wit different client id. here is my mistake

Comment: hi, kindly i would like to inquire about whther or not i am able to use passwrd and username in my pub and sub messages? i read the to use a pass and username you should have al least mosquitto V3.1 and mine is V 1.3.5. now i do not know whther my version is V 1.3.5 or V 3.5 because in a website they specified the version as a set of 2 numbers and mine is 3 numbers.moreover, the pass and user name are never working in my messages

Comment: The comments aren't really an appropriate place for a discussion.

Comment: What might also be a bit tricky is that the client receives the messages directly after it connects. At that point, callbacks might not be installed, so that's another possibility to miss the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the messages with the retain flag to be able to recieve the messages when you re-connect. The QoS defines how hard the broker/client will try to ensure that a message is received.

Have a read here http://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html on QOS, clean session and retained messages.

Comment: it says in the QoS section. ..... This means that when the client disconnects, any subscriptions it has will remain and any subsequent QoS 1 or 2 messages will be stored until it connects again in the future.

Comment: @Matt - retained messages are a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ralight is correct and addresses conceptually most things where mistakes tend to happen.

However I would like to add to his answer with a specific nuance with Java MQTT Client Paho org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3. I had followed the entire steps mentioned by @ralight and it was still not recieving QOS >=1 message on client reconnect to the broker. The main issue here was with the way Paho client was initialized. For reference I will taken an open source kafka connect mqtt connector implementation https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/master/src/main/java/be/jovacon/kafka/connect/MQTTSourceTask.java#L33

This implementation has issue that it doesn't recieve messages which were send when the client was disconnected and reconnects back with cleanSession false and subscribe qos >= 1 (Well in my testing it did recieve some messages a few times flakily).

The solution to this is

- Old Code

  - Initialize Client
  - Connect Client
  - Subscribe
  - Code https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/master/src/main/java/be/jovacon/kafka/connect/MQTTSourceTask.java#L33
- New Code

  - Initialize Client
  - Set Callback on Client (Call mqttClient.setCallback before call to connect with messageArrived callback which will recieve the old messages)
  - Connect Client
  - Subscribe
  - Code Changes https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt/compare/master...thehellmaker:kafka-connect-mqtt:master