# How to store data mqtt when offline and send them when online

Tags: android, mqtt

I have a problem, when my connection intrupted, mqtt publish not send at reconnect, how to resolve it? Im following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973300/4168314) but not working

**What I've done** :

- Im already implement a service mqtt to send gps location and work as usual when online.
- Set Qos to 1.
- Set ClientId fixed.
- Set Publish Qos to 1.
- Set clean session to false

But the result when I reconnect still publish data when I online & not publishing stored persistence data.

**Here is my source code:**

```
package id.trustudio.android.mdm.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import id.trustudio.android.mdm.http.DetectConnection;
import id.trustudio.android.mdm.util.Cons;
import id.trustudio.android.mdm.util.Debug;
import id.trustudio.android.mdm.util.GPSTracker;
import id.trustudio.android.mdm.util.GPSTracker2;

public class MqttService extends Service implements MqttCallback {

    public static boolean isStarted = false;

    private double latitude  = 0;
    private double longitude = 0;
    private GPSTracker mGPSTracker;
    private GPSTracker2 mGPSTracker2;

    boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    private SharedPreferences mPrivatePref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private DetectConnection mDetectConnection;
    String deviceID,Name;
    int totalbyte;
    String packages;
    MemoryPersistence persistence;
    String clientId;
    MqttAndroidClient client;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPrivatePref = this.getSharedPreferences(Cons.PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = mPrivatePref.edit();

        deviceID = mPrivatePref.getString(Cons.APP_PACKAGE + "deviceid", "");
        Name = mPrivatePref.getString(Cons.APP_PACKAGE + "user", "");

        clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        client =
                new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "tcp://broker.administrasi.id:1883",
                        clientId, persistence);

        client.setCallback(this);

        try{
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
            client.connect(connOpts,null, new IMqttActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {

                        }
                    });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTask, 1000);
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        //check if your service is already started
        if (isStarted){      //yes - do nothing
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        } else {             //no
            isStarted = true;
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            getLatLng();
            if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) getLatLngWifi();

                        Debug.e("MQTT","Connect");
                        String topic = "gps/kodeupi/kodeap/kodeup/" + deviceID;
                        Debug.e("MQTT CLIENT", clientId);
                        int qos = 1;
                        try {
                            IMqttToken subToken = client.subscribe(topic, qos);
                            subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                                    // The message was published

                                    String topic = "gps/kodeupi/kodeap/kodeup/" + deviceID;
                                    long CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                    String payload = deviceID + "|" + latitude + "|" + longitude + "|" + CurrentTime;

                                    byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
                                    try {
                                        encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
                                        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                                        client.publish(topic, message);
                                        message.setRetained(true);
                                        // set quality of service
                                        message.setQos(1);
                                        Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess");
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken,
                                                      Throwable exception) {
                                    // The subscription could not be performed, maybe the user was not
                                    // authorized to subscribe on the specified topic e.g. using wildcards

                                }
                            });
                        } catch (MqttException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
        }
    };

    private void getLatLng() {
        mGPSTracker2        = new GPSTracker2(this);
        isInternetPresent   = mDetectConnection.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isInternetPresent == true) {
            if (mGPSTracker2.canGetLocation()) {
                latitude    = mGPSTracker2.getLatitude();
                longitude   = mGPSTracker2.getLongitude();

                if(latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                    editor.putString(Cons.APP_LATITUDE, latitude+"");
                    editor.putString(Cons.APP_LONGITUDE, longitude+"");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } else {
//              getLatLngWifi();
                Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "on gps failed, please check");

            }
        } else {
            Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "no connection");

            if(mGPSTracker2 != null)
                mGPSTracker2.stopUsingGPS();
        }
    }

    private void getLatLngWifi() {
        mGPSTracker         = new GPSTracker(this);
        isInternetPresent   = mDetectConnection.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (isInternetPresent == true) {
            if (mGPSTracker.canGetLocation()) {
                latitude    = mGPSTracker.getLatitude();
                longitude   = mGPSTracker.getLongitude();

                if(latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                    editor.putString(Cons.APP_LATITUDE, latitude+"");
                    editor.putString(Cons.APP_LONGITUDE, longitude+"");
                    editor.commit();
                }

            } else {
                Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "wifi " + "on gps failed, please check");

            }
        } else {
            Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "wifi " + "no connection");

            if(mGPSTracker != null)
                mGPSTracker.stopUsingGPS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: The answer in the linked to question is how to get messages delivered to a client that has been disconnected, not how to send messages from a disconnected client when it reconnects. If you try and publish a message while the client is disconnected it will throw an exception, it is up to you to catch that exception and store the message to be resent once reconnected.

Comment: Also you are setting the QOS and retained flags after the message has been published, this will not work as the message is already gone.

Comment: Is there any callback on library for do that or I must implement my own script to do that ?

Comment: You have to implement it yourself

Comment: @hardillb thanks for suggestion i will try to implement it by myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As laid out in the comments.

This is something you have to code yourself, there is no support for storing messages that have not been sent because the client is disconnected in the framework. The MQTT persistence is only used to ensure messages with QOS 1/2 are not lost in flight if the connection to the broker goes down before the QOS handshake is complete.

If you try to publish a message while disconnected the `client.publish(topic, message)` call will throw an exception, you need to catch this exception and then make arrangements to store the content of the message for when the connection is re-established. Once a connection is back up and running then you need to iterate over the stored details and try the send again.

Answer (score 2):

So here the sample, as hardillb answer Im make my own implement to store data to local database and send all at the connection re-etablished.

**here my source code**

```
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
      private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            getLatLng();
            if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) getLatLngWifi();

                        Debug.e("MQTT","Connect");
                        String topic = "gps/kodeupi/kodeap/kodeup/" + deviceID;
                        Debug.e("MQTT CLIENT", clientId);
                        int qos = 1;
                        try {
                            IMqttToken subToken = client.subscribe(topic, qos);
                            subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                                    // The message was published
                                     mList = getLocationAll();//call all data stored on sqlite
                        Debug.e("MQTT","Connected. Size list = "+mList.size());

                        if(mList.size() > 0){//if data found then send in looping
                                    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size() ; i++) {
                                     final String Latitude = mList.get(i).latitude;
                                     final String Longitude = mList.get(i).longitude;
                                     final String timestamps = mList.get(i).CurrentTimes;

                                     String payload = deviceID + "|" + timestamps + "|" + Name + "|" + Latitude + "|" + Longitude;

                                byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
                                try {
                                    encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
                                    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                                    // set quality of service
                                    client.publish(topic, message);
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                }

                               DeleteAllLocation();

                            }
                                    String topic = "gps/kodeupi/kodeap/kodeup/" + deviceID;
                                    long CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                    String payload = deviceID + "|" + latitude + "|" + longitude + "|" + CurrentTime;

                                    byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
                                    try {
                                        encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
                                        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                                        client.publish(topic, message);
                                        message.setRetained(true);
                                        // set quality of service
                                        message.setQos(1);
                                        Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess");
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken,
                                                      Throwable exception) {
                                    // The subscription could not be performed, maybe the user was not
                                    // authorized to subscribe on the specified topic e.g. using wildcards
                                    long CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    addLocation(deviceID, CurrentTime+"", Name,     latitude+"" , longitude+""); //add data to sqlite when offline
                                    Debug.e("MQTT","Failure");

                                }
                            });
                        } catch (MqttException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
        }
    };
```

**here my sqlite to store & delete data**

```
 public void addLocation( String device_id, String timestamp, String user_id, String latitude, String longitude) {
    if (sqLite == null) {
        Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "null database");
        return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("device_id", device_id);
    values.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    values.put("user_id", user_id);
    values.put("latitude", latitude);
    values.put("longitude", longitude);

    Debug.i(Cons.TAG, "Insert location : title = " + device_id);

    sqLite.insert("tbl_location", null, values);
}

public ArrayList<LocationModel> getLocationAll() {
    ArrayList<LocationModel> result = new ArrayList<LocationModel>();
    if (sqLite == null || result == null) {
        return result;
    }

    String sql  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_location ORDER BY timestamp ASC";

    Cursor c    = sqLite.rawQuery(sql, null);

    int device_id       = c.getColumnIndex("device_id");
    int timestamp       = c.getColumnIndex("timestamp");
    int userid          = c.getColumnIndex("user_id");
    int latitude        = c.getColumnIndex("latitude");
    int longitude           = c.getColumnIndex("longitude");

    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                LocationModel mApps = new LocationModel();

                mApps.DeviceId      = c.getInt(device_id);
                mApps.CurrentTimes  = c.getString(timestamp);
                mApps.UserId        = c.getString(userid);
                mApps.latitude      = c.getString(latitude);
                mApps.longitude     = c.getString(longitude);

                result.add(mApps);

                c.moveToNext();
            }

            c.close();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public void DeleteAllLocation() {
    if (sqLite == null)
        return;

    sqLite.delete("tbl_location", null, null);
}
```