# Paho MQTT message reliability when client disconnects

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mqtt, paho

I am working on a MQTT kafka source connector. The messages are
   coming from MQTT Publisher then connector will subscribed to MQTT
   topic(/iot/sensor/#) and those messages will published to Kafka
   broker. But in  mean while if I stop the connector and again 
   restarted the connector then connector is consuming messages from
   mqtt broker but some of the mqtt messages are missing(If i send 1000
   messages from MQTT publisher and not getting 1000 mesages in kafka )
   *I give the mqtt ClientID is Unique name. I set the mqtt paho client
   properites with setCleanSession=false,QOS=1 and use the
   MqttDefaultFilePersistence(DIR)*. Rabbitmq version is 3.6.10

PseudoCode

```
Public class MyTask extends SourceTask implements MqttCallback{
//Initialzied the queue
@Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> map) {
    //set necessary properties and configuration
    //set the required mqttConnect options and mqtt broker
     Paho mClient = new MqttClient(mqttURl,Unique ClientID, new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(DIR))
     mClient.connect(RequiredConnectProperties)
    }
    @Override
    public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
    //poll the queue
    // publish messages to kafka
    }
    @Override
    public void stop() {
    //disconnect the mqtt paho clent
    }
    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String mqtttopic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    //add the messages to queue

    }
}
```

Comment: That is the way Mqtt works. When the broker receives a message on a topic it is published to all subscribers on that topic. If you aren't subscribed on the topic when the message is published (e.g. by a disconnect) you also won't receive it. The only native way around this is setting the `retainedFlag` to true which will keep the last received message on the topic and send it to a new subscriber on subscription. Other than that you can only go with a custom system/broker that keeps all messages and forwards them to new subscribers - although in that case you probably shouldn't use Mqtt.

Comment: @Ben this is not the case for QOS 1 or QOS 2 subscriptions. At high QOS if you have been subscribed to a topic and you reconnect with the same client id and cleansession set to false then the broker should queue the messages and deliver them when you reconnect and subscribe to those topics again

Comment: @hardillb that is indeed true. I just assumed QoS = 0 to be used which was wrong. I stand corrected. In that case the problem could lie in the persistence of the broker which does not correctly store the session to be resumed. I would check there. But it's something that in theory at least should work with QoS 1/2.

Comment: what actions can be taken in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: @hardillb Do I need MQTT publisher also having QOS 1  and Clean session true?

Comment: No, publish and subscribe should be independent with regards to QOS

Comment: @hardillb I tested connector  multiple times but sometimes i am getting exact message count

Comment: How is this related to RabbitMQ? Removing that tag for now.

Comment: @hardillb how to get debug for rabbitmq by using log4j.properties?

Comment: In order to create a persistent session, messages should be pub/sub QoS > 0 and cleanSession= false. A very good explanation with examples can be found here
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-clean-sessions-example/

Comment: Please refer to my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971783/with-the-clear-session-flag-set-to-false-i-am-missing-the-published-values. I have faced the same issue and fixed it